# Burn AVI with embedded subtitles to DVD on a Mac?

Tags: macos, dvd, avi, subtitles, dvd-burning

I have an AVI file that has subtitles within the file itself (no .srt) that I need to burn to DVD on a Mac for a presentation at work. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with trying Handbrake, but would also like to suggest [SmallDVD](http://www.smallsoftware.co.uk/smalldvd/). It converts and authors a DVD in one step. Perhaps its conversion will burn in your subtitles.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/)? Use it to convert your video to something Quicktime understands, then use iDVD.

Comment: when I convert the video, the subtitles get lost, at least with FFMpeg

Comment: Maybe it only works with certain formats. One can rip DVDs with subtitles to H.264/AAC with Handbrake.

Comment: @redlago: But did you try Handbrake? There's a subtitle section that allows you to select the subtitle track and burn it in.

Comment: -1 Because Handbrake dropped support for Xvid/Divx (.avi files). Encoding videos with the above encoding is no longer possible.

Comment: @Ory As I only use Handbrake to convert DVDs to MP4/AAC, I didn't know that. Also, the avi container does not necessarily imply DivX/XviD: I've seen avi containers with MP4/AAC or WMV/WMA.

Comment: @CajunLuke: The question asked regarding DVDs, where most support DivX/XviD along with the normal DVD encoding. Wanted to make sure people understand this answer is no longer relevant.